# Create generic file for DynamicReports

Tags: java, report, reporting, dynamic-reports

I have a web application with many catalogues(more than 200), and I want to create *PDF* and *XSL* reports for them. User just has filters by table parameters. 
To create reports I am considering `DynamicReports` library. And by the examples in the site I see the following code:

```
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
report
  .columns(
      Columns.column("Customer Id", "id", DataTypes.integerType()),
      Columns.column("First Name", "first_name", DataTypes.stringType()),
      Columns.column("Last Name", "last_name", DataTypes.stringType()),
      Columns.column("Date", "date", DataTypes.dateType()))
  .title(//title of the report
      Components.text("SimpleReportExample")
      .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
      .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())//show page number on the page footer
      .setDataSource("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, date FROM customers",
                              connection);
```

So, how I said before, I have many catalogues, and I don't want list all table parameters for each table by hand.

How I can create Generic class, which will create fields automatically or suggest me some useful hint. 
Help me with application design. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am also using the same dynamic reports to generate report. Here what i am doing is, i will upload json file which contains the report information like query id, which columns should display, and its styles and all. By parsing the json i will get all the details and by executing the query i will get data.